# Existence of a compact Hausdorff space which continuously embeds into itself as a set with no interior.

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

Is there an example of a compact Hausdorff space $X$ together with a continuous injection $\iota \colon X \hookrightarrow X$ such that $\iota(X)$ has empty interior (relative to $X$)?

Comment: While "reputation" is no big deal to me, it's still unpleasant to get "punished", say, by removal of 15pt. And I don't have a clue why and how. I don't see anything special or strange on this page (fortunately, not a trace of any conflict). Do you have any idea of what has happened? Should I ask on meta?

Comment: So I changed the "accepted answer" to your second response, but I'm surprised that that the +15 reputation was just removed and not rewarded to the new "accepted answer". I'm very sorry if it's removed reputation!

Comment: @Zorno, no big deal, everything's is fine! (I am glad that there was only some random formal "discontinuity" but no bad will).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\, Z\ne\emptyset\, $ be an arbitrary Hausdorff compact space such that $\, Z\, $ has no isolated point (is dense in itself) and $\, X\, := Z^2\, $ is homeomorphic to $\, Z.\, $ The Hilbert cube and Cantor discontinuum are such $\, Z.\, $

Also, for every non-empty Hausdorff compact space $\, Y\, $ which has no isolated point, let $\, Z\, $ be a Tikhonov infinite product of copies of $\, Y.\, $ Then again $\, X:=Z^2\, $ is homeomorphic to $\, Z.\, $

In all these examples of $\, X := Z^2,\, $ it is homeomorphic to
$\, Z\times\{p\}\, $ where $\, p\in X\, $ is arbitrary.
And $\, Z\times\{p\}\, $ has empty interior in $\, X.\, $ Thus, each
such space $\, X\, $ provides an example for
the  ***OP's Question***.

Comment: Thanks for this class of examples! Although it's not part of the original question, do you know if it's possible space $X$ satisfying the question such that $0 < \dim(X) < \infty$, where $\dim(X)$ is the covering dimension of $X$?

Comment: @Zorngo, indeed, an arbitrary dimension is possible (see my addition to my first *Answer*). Thank you for asking good questions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example, based on the Cantor discontinuum $\, C\, $ which
consists of all real numbers $\, r\in[0;1]\, $ which have only $\, 0\, $
and $\, 2\, $ in their ternary positional decomposition.

Let $\, X\, :=\, C^2\, \subseteq\, \mathbb R^2,\, $ and let
$\, h:X\rightarrow C\times\{0\}\, $ be a homeorphism (it's well known that
it exists). Then $\, C\times\{0\}\, $ has empty interior in $\, X.\, $
To be pedantic, consider the homeomorphic embedding of $\, X\, $ into
$\, X\, $ (i.e. injective continuus map) induced by $\, h,\, $ and we
are done.   *Great!*

> **EXTRA:**

Starting from an arbitrary requested example $\,(X\ A)\,$ (where
$\, X\ A\,$ are homeomorphic, and $\,A\subseteq X\, $ has empty interior
with respect to $\,X),\,$ we obtain further examples of this type:

$$ (X\times Q\quad A\times Q) $$

where $Q$ is an arbitrary non-empty (compact) topological space.

This way, if we start with a $0$-dimensional $X,\,$ we can obtain examples of arbitrary finite or infinite dimensions.

Comment: That would do it, thanks! For some reason I'd been avoiding cantor-like constructions because clopen sets are as far from empty interior as you can get.

Comment: One way or another, "clopen" is not an issue here.